# Why can I create files in Node.js command line but not in program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

```js
let path = `./backups/${new Date().toISOString()}.json`;
let text = JSON.stringify(db.all());
fs.appendFile(path, text, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`Backup successful to ${fileName}`);
});
```

Whenever I try and run this through Node I always get the error Error: "ENOENT: no such file or directory"
Any suggestions greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Because you are appending - and appending only happens when original file exists

Comment: [Not actually](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback): "append data to a file, creating the file if it does not yet exist". I guess it's just some kind of permission issue.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález in that case it should have failed with an EACCES though.

Comment: The backups folder doesn't exist?  Also, consider using a different timestamping format.  Not every filesystem is going to allow you to put colons in the path.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you go about creating a file:

1. Check if the directory exists and your program has access to the location.
2. If yes in both the cases, get all your data in place and create a file in the location and put it in. Add mode data if you need after this to the file.
3. If even one of them in point 1 is `no' solve that and do point 2.

Answer (score 0):

Error ended up being the colon's in new Date().toISOString().
I changed it to 
    let path = `./backups/${new Date().toISOString()}.json`.replace(':', ',');
and this now works. Thanks to Brad in the comments for pointing this out.